# Google Maps v2 GGroundOverlay not rendering until screen resize

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on a google map based thing using V2 (which I know is deprecated, it's legacy code). I have a function I call in several places (picking an existing "pin", dropping a new "pin") that renders an images as a "range" around the selected point.

the "map" that's passed in here is a GMap object. centrePt is a GLatLng, and rangeValue is an int, gotten from a jQueryTools slider control.

```
function drawCircle(map, centrePt, rangeValue) {
    if (circle) {
        map.removeOverlay(circle);
    }
     var boundaries = getBoundaries(centrePt, rangeValue);
     circle = new GGroundOverlay("/images/map_range.png", boundaries);
     map.addOverlay(circle);

}
```

I have this running on MANY pages, and in many contexts it works just great.

In one particular page, the image at `/images/map_range.png` doesn't display. The slider slides, the values underlying it definitely update (I'm watching that with Firebug), this function fires (and writes to the console, when I had that in there), but no circle... UNTIL the window resizes. Literally I can slide on the slider, no circle, resize the window by a few pixels, slide on the slider, and get the circle.

WHY would a window resize make this suddenly work? Any thoughts? Cause I'm stumped.

I tried generating a window resize, but evidently I'm not allowed to mess with the size of a window I didn't launch, which I guess on the balance I approve of.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem, with OpenLayers. The map is hidden in an ajax tab, when chosen it only displays a subsection, yet resizing the window seems to fire off an extra event (I can see the images load via the firebug net tab) and the full map loads. I can't work out the cause yet (although i suspect it's related to the  focus). My only potential fix is to 'fake' a screen resize in someway.

Comment: Also, I only get the problem in Firefox!